# Reading data from a text file into a struct with different data types c#

Tags: c#, struct, streamreader, doubly-linked-list

I have a text file that stores data about cars, its call car.txt. I want to read this text file and categorize each of the sections for each car. Ultimately I want to add this information into a doubly linked list. So far everything I have tried is either giving me format exception or out of range exception.
This is my public structure

```
public struct cars
    {
        public int id;
        public string Make;
        public string Model;
        public double Year;
        public double Mileage;
        public double Price;
    }
```

This is where  I try reading the data into the struct then add it to the DLL

```
static void Main()
        {
            int Key;
            cars item = new cars();
            int preKey;
            /* create an empty double linked list */
            DoubleLinkedList DLL = new DoubleLinkedList();
            string line;
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Esther\Desktop\cars.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                var array = line.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                item.Make =array[0];
                item.Model = array[1];
                item.Year = Double.Parse(array[2]);
                item.Mileage = Double.Parse(array[2]);
                item.Price = Double.Parse(array[2]);
                // Using newline to seprate each line of the file.
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            DLL.AppendToHead(item);

            }
```

This is throws a format exception then an out of range exception. How do I get this code to read the text file into the struct and add it to my DLL? This is the car.txt file

```
 BMW
 228i
 2008
 122510
 7800

 Honda
 Accord
 2011
 93200
 9850

 Toyota
 Camry
 2010
 85300
 9500
```

Comment: Why do you split a whole line again by `"\r\n", "\n"`? And why do you read `array[2]` three times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your double-linked list to a plain `List<cars>` for simplicity. You need to create a new `cars` item for each record, otherwise you'll end up with every element in your list referring to the same record (the last one processed). Each line has a different attribute of the car so you need to work out which attribute to save, using a counter (`idx`).

```
    using System.Collections.Generic; // for List<cars>
    ... ... ...
    public static void ReadMultiline()
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945520/reading-data-from-a-text-file-into-a-struct-with-different-data-types-c-sharp
        var DLL = new List<cars>();
        string line;
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"cars.txt");
        var item = new cars();
        int idx = 0;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            idx++;
            switch ( idx ) {
                case 1: item.Make = line; break;
                case 2: item.Model = line; break;
                case 3: item.Year = Double.Parse(line); break;
                case 4: item.Mileage = Double.Parse(line); break;
                case 5: item.Price = Double.Parse(line); break;
            }
            if (line == "" && idx > 0 )
            {
                DLL.Add(item);
                idx = 0;
                item = new cars();  // create new cars item
            }
        }
        // pick up the last one if not saved
        if (idx > 0 )
            DLL.Add(item);

        foreach( var x in DLL )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Make={0} Model={1} Year={2} Mileage={3} Price={4}", x.Make, x.Model, x.Year, x.Mileage, x.Price) );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file line by line with `ReadLine`, and trying to split a single line with a line ending. This will result in an array with just one element (E.G. "BMW")

You can either read the whole file and then split by lines or just assume that each line will contain some data.

The `OutOfRangeException` refers to your invocation of `array[1]` when the array contains only `array[0] = "BMW"`.